# Hello! Could you help me find z that verify the inequality $|z^{n+1}-z^n| \geq |z^{n+1}-1|+|z^{n+1}-z| $ with $z \in \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

We need to find z that verify the inequality $|z^{n+1}-z^n|\geq|z^{n+1}-1|+|z^{n+1}-z| $ with $z \in \mathbb{C}$   and $n \in \mathbb{N}, n\geq 2$.

I divided the inequality by $|z^{n+1}|$ and set $\frac{1}{z}=w$. I proved $|w|=1$ and $|1-w|=|1-w^{n+1}|+|1-w^{n}|$, but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: $w=1$ works so assume $w\ne 1$ and divide by $1-w$ so you get $1 \ge |1+..w^n|+|1+..w^{n-1}| =|1+..w^n|+|w+..w^n| \ge |(1+..w^n)-(w+..w^n)|=1$ so you must have equality hence $1+..w^n, w+...w^n$ point in opposite directions or one is $0$ - the second case gives roots of unity or order $n$ or $n=1$ which work and the first case gives $1+(a+1)w+...(a+1)w^n=0, a>0$ etc

Comment: I don't really understand...If $|1+..w^n|+|w+..w^n|=|(1+..w^n)−(w+..w^n)|=1$ why do we conclude $1+..w^n, w+...w^n $point in opposite directions or one is 0 ?

Comment: in the triangle inequality $|x|+|y| \ge |x-y|$ we have equality precisely if either is $0$ or $y=-ax, a>0$

Comment: Thank you very much!